# Can I use `hana::keys` without an instance of the structure?

Tags: c++, boost, struct, c++14, boost-hana

The [documentation](https://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Struct.html#gaf8c7199742581e6e66c8397def68e2d3) for `hana::keys` says that I can use it in function call syntax e.g. `hana::keys(s)` where `s` is an instance of a class meeting the concept `hana::Struct`, and it returns a sequence of key objects.

A related function, `hana::accessors`, returns a sequence of accessor functions which can be used to grab the corresponding members from an instance of the struct.

`hana::accessors` [can be used in two ways](https://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Struct.html#ga983a55dbd93d766fd37689ea32e4ddfb):

```
hana::accessors(s)
hana::accessors<S>()
```

are both legal, `constexpr` functions returning the same thing when `S = decltype(s)` -- the sequence corresponding to structure `S`.

When I try this syntax with `hana::keys`, I get an error. Here's an MCVE, adapted from an example in `hana` documentation:

---

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/define_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/keys.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

struct Person {
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Person,
        (std::string, name),
        (unsigned short, age)
    );
};


// Debug print a single structure

template <typename T>
void debug_print_field(const char * name, const T & value) {
  std::cout << "\t" << name << ": " << value << std::endl;
}


template <typename S>
void debug_print(const S & s) {
  std::cout << "{\n";

  hana::for_each(hana::keys<S>(), [&s] (auto key) {
    debug_print_field(hana::to<char const *>(key), hana::at_key(s, key));
  });

  std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
}

// Debug print compare two structures

int main() {
    Person john{"John", 30}, kevin{"Kevin", 20};

    debug_print(john);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    debug_print(kevin);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

---

```
$ g++-6 -std=c++14 -I/home/chris/boost/boost_1_61_0/ main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘void debug_print(const S&)’:
main.cpp:28:30: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
   hana::for_each(hana::keys<S>(), [&s] (auto key) {
                              ^
main.cpp:28:32: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
   hana::for_each(hana::keys<S>(), [&s] (auto key) {
                                ^
```

---

It works fine when I use `hana::keys(s)`.

But in my actual application, I don't have an instance of the structure, it's only a template parameter.

As a hack, I made this:

```
// Work around for `hana::keys`

template <typename S>
constexpr decltype(auto) get_hana_keys() {
  return decltype(hana::keys(std::declval<S>())){};
}
```

I *believe* that this works based on my limited understanding of implementation details of `hana` described in the docu. -- `hana::keys` is supposed to return a sequence of compile-time strings, and all of the information is contained in the type, so just getting the type and default constructing it should be equivalent.

When I use `get_hana_keys<S>()` in my MCVE then it compiles and runs fine.

However I don't know if it's really correct, or if the assumptions I'm making go beyond what the docs allow me to assume.

I am using boost version `1.61` and `gcc 6.2.0`.

What I would like to know is,

- Is there a good reason that `hana::keys<S>()` doesn't work or is this simply an oversight? `hana` seems to have been very meticulously designed so I'm inclined to second-guess myself here.
- Is there anything wrong with the hack I created or a way to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question!

> Is there a good reason that `hana::keys<S>()` doesn't work or is this simply an oversight?

The reason why `hana::keys<S>()` does not work is that there's no way to implement it in the general case. Indeed, `keys` was initially designed for `hana::map`, where the keys *could* be stateful and so you really need an object to return something meaningful. The fact that an object is not necessary to retrieve the keys of a `hana::Struct` is just a coincidence.

> Is there anything wrong with the hack I created or a way to improve it?

Technically, `hana::string` is not documented as being default-constructible, so default-constructing a `hana::tuple` of those is not guaranteed to work. However, this is an oversight which I've fixed in [1eebdb](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/commit/1eebdb62cb7169cb40830f855890aadf30b8a3d2), so you're good.

That being said, a perhaps more idiomatic solution would be the following:

```
template <typename S>
constexpr auto get_hana_keys() {
  return hana::transform(hana::accessors<S>(), hana::first);
}
```

In fact, this is how we define `hana::keys` for `hana::Struct`s.

Finally, note that everything related to `hana::Struct` will be much better served by language-level reflection, so please excuse the quirky support for reflection that Hana provides. It's really hard to do anything good in that area without language support.